# Torrent downloads fine on one connection but very slowly on another

Tags: networking, download, bittorrent, adsl

I’ve been downloading a fairly large torrent (it’s about 30gb of some stuff a friend overseas put together for me, mostly anime) for a while now.

When I download from home, I get *download speeds up to 400kB/s*. However, if I download from my girlfriend’s house, I’m *lucky to get even 1kB/s**.

As far as the configuration of these 2 Internet connections is concerned, I know very little other than the fact that both connections are the same. Both are on 4mbps ADSL lines which are shaped where traffic is split 3.5mbps download and 0.5mbps upload and that the ISPs are different.

As for the torrent, well, it’s the same between the two connections. Trackers don’t change or anything so I’m really confused as to what configurations on the connection where the thing downloads slower would cause the slow down.

Answer (score 3):

One ISP could be blocking p2p traffic while the other isn't. That would be my guess. A second possibility is that the modem/router/firewall could be preventing that type of traffic. As it sounds like it may be legally questionable I don't think calling your girlfriend's ISP is going to get you much luck and may end up causing issues for her continuing her web service.

Comment: I don't plan on doing anything about it though. I just wanted to understand it. Thanks

Comment: No problem, glad to help! Let me know if you have any other questions/need anything else :)

Answer (score -2):

First, they're not '*4Mbit DSL lines split*'. Not how it works. 3.5 down and 0.5 up is 3.5 down and 0.5 up. there's a LOT more capacity, it's just those are hte speeds they've decided to run at.

now, the reasons, could be the setup. Badly configured clients (especially if you follow some youtube guide or similar) can make it slow. Being firewalls will as well, as you're having to make all the connections, rather than people connecting to you. It could also be the router. Some are just really low-end (especially if they're ISP-provided) and don't like the multitude of connections that bittorrent can throw at it.

Also, trackers have ABSOLUTELY NOTHING to do with speeds, any more than telephone directories alter the speed you talk to a business on the phone.

As for the above commenter, there's plenty of legal uses for bittorrent (the whole Net Neutrality thing with the FCC in the US is over ISP's messing with bittorrent (I know, because it was my research that started it).

Redo the settings with the clients in-built speedguide (ctrl+g on utorrent, other clients see their documentation) and remember that the speed settings are based on your **UPLOAD** speed, not download, so 0.5Mbit for you.

Then try a torrent like a linux ISO, or libreoffice, because they're extremely well seeded. If you're not getting ~400Kbytes/sec (your line max) then there's something wrong with your connection, and don't be afraid to contact your ISP.